# Workaround for break-word in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, textarea

I'm using a conjunction of the styles `white-space: pre` and `word-wrap: break-word` to allow soft wraps anywhere in a textarea, regardless of word boundaries.

```css
textarea { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre; word-wrap: break-word; }
```

```html
<textarea cols="40" rows="10">
(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)
</textarea>
```

**This is what I want**, and what I'm getting in all browsers except Firefox.

[image: What I want]

**This is what Firefox renders**: apparently, the `word-wrap` style is ignored.

[image: What Firefox renders]

Finally, just let me show what happens if `white-space: pre` is removed. Note how lines only break after parentheses. In this case `word-wrap: break-word` makes no difference at all. I don't want this either.

[image: No white-space no good]

So my question is, how can I convince Firefox to format my sample user input in a textarea like in the first picture, allowing soft wraps after any character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `word-break: break-all;` and `white-space: pre-line;`

```css
textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="41" rows="10">(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)(ABCDefgh1234)</textarea>
```

Comment: You might not see this working on page load, try to resize the textarea